# Periods vs. colons as separator between time parts of GETUTCDATE()

Tags: sql-server

When I run `GETUTCDATE()` in SSMS I get a datetime that uses colons as the separator between hours-minutes and minutes-seconds, as in this example:

```
2020-02-28T07:19:55Z
```

To help investigate an bug I'm working on, I would like `GETUTCDATE()` to use periods instead of colons, as in this example:

```
2020-02-28T07.19.55Z
```

Is there a way to do this?  I've tried setting the Control Panel setting for Short Time and Long Time to use periods instead of colons, but that didn't change what `GETUTCDATE()` returns.

Do I need to do something with language settings or some sort of culture/region settings?

Answer (score 1):

GetUtcDate() does what it does, and you can't change it. Even the string you see is only a convenience provided by your query tool (SSMS), as the actual DateTime value returned is *binary* and not human readable.

What you can do is this:

```
REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, GETUTCDATE(), 127), ':', '.');
```

Just keep in mind you're now working a with a varchar value rather than a datetime value now.

Comment: Thanks, Joel.  Just so I'm clear, I'm wondering if the language/region/culture/whatever setings for my computer itself could be set so that GETUTCDATE() uses periods instead of colons.  I'm guessing/hoping that GETUTCDATE() looks at the computer's info and decides whether to use periods or colons.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I hear what you're asking. What you're missing is `GetUtcDate()` does not return formatted text at all. The value you see in SSMS is only a convenience provided by the tool, and the colons you're looking at on the screen are not directly produced by the `GetUtcDate()` function. Instead, `GetUtcDate()` returns a **binary** datetime value. Therefore, cultural settings on your computer will not make any difference at all.

Comment: I think I see.  One last question just to be sure I'm completely clear:  Is it the case that for a given time, that GETUTCDATE() will return the exact same binary value whether a computure's "culture" is such that its SSMS display used colons or periods?